# convert the paramater's date type to varchar , of stored procedure in linq query

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have created this stored procedure to filter products by `type`, `category`, `country`, `subsidary`, `date`.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindIncomplete_Products]
     @type nvarchar(250),
     @category nvarchar(250),
     @country nvarchar(250),
     @subsidary nvarchar(250),
     @date datetime
AS
Begin  
    select  [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductID],
            [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductTitleEn],
            [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductTitleAr], 
            [dbo].[AB_Product].[Status],
            [dbo].[AB_ProductType].[ProductTypeNameEn],
            [dbo].[AB_ProductType].[ProductTypeNameAr], 
            [dbo].[AB_ProductTypeCategory].[ProductCategoryNameEn],
            [dbo].[AB_ProductTypeCategory].[ProductCategoryNameAr],
            [dbo].[AB_Subsidary].[SubsidaryNameEn],
            [dbo].[AB_Subsidary].[SubsidaryNameAr],
            [dbo].[AB_Subsidary].[Country]
    from 
        [dbo].[AB_Product]
    inner join 
        [dbo].[AB_ProductType] on [dbo].[AB_ProductType].[ProductTypeID] = [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductTypeID]
    inner join 
        [dbo].[AB_ProductTypeCategory] on [dbo].[AB_ProductTypeCategory].[ProductCategoryID] = [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductCategoryID]
    inner join 
        [dbo].[AB_Subsidary] on [dbo].[AB_Subsidary].[SubsidaryID] = [dbo].[AB_Product].[Subsidary_ID]
    WHERE 
       (@type IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductTypeID]  LIKE '%' +  @type + '%')
       AND (@category IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductCategoryID] LIKE '%' +  @category + '%')
       AND (@country IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Subsidary].[Country] LIKE '%' +  @country + '%')
       AND (@subsidary IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Product].[Subsidary_ID] LIKE '%' +  @subsidary + '%')
       AND (@date IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Product].[CreatedDate] LIKE '%' +  @date + '%')
End
```

I'm passing the parameter values through LINQ query in my C# controller class. This is that linq query

```
public ActionResult Program_Search(string type, string category, string country, string subsidary, DateTime? date)
{
     var incomplete_product_result = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProductCollection>("FindIncomplete_Products  @type = {0}, @category = {1}, @country = {2}, @subsidary = {3}, @date = {4}", type, category, country, subsidary, date).ToList();

    return View(incomplete_product_result);
}
```

Once  try to pass parameters by binding with URL like follow

```
http://localhost:49669/Home/Program_Search?type=002&category=null&subsidary=null&country=null&date=12/12/1889
```

I'm getting following error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Comment: here Im trying to pass parameters through linq query

Comment: Did you try with `string date` instead of `DateTime? date` in parameter list? and try changing `convert(nvarchar(25), @date, 121)` to `convert(datetime, @date, 121)` as your receiving parameter in SP is datetime not nvarchar

Comment: you meant for initial "date" parameter in control class ?

Comment: Yes, you can try three things one after another.. Use `string date` in place of `DateTime? date` in parameter list.. use `convert(datetime, @date, 121)` in place of `convert(nvarchar(25), @date, 121)` and while hitting URL pass data value as `date='12/12/1889'`

Comment: do i need to do any change in my stored procedure also ?

Comment: @AmneshGoel I'm getting this error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'.`once I add that in this line `var incomplete_product_result = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProductCollection>("FindIncomplete_Products  @type = {0}, @category = {1}, @country = {2}, @subsidary = {3}, convert(datetime, @date, 121) = {4}", type, category, country, subsidary, date).ToList();`

Comment: @kez You declared  '@date datetime' in store procedure and in Like query you are trying compare it in string format.

Comment: @kez you don't need to change anything in your SP

Comment: @kez okay just make two changes.. change incoming parameter type to string instead of nullable date... and then revert to your old convert(nvarchar(25)... and give a try

Comment: Actually I can make 1st change which is change the DateTime to string , but don't know where I do that convertion `convert(varchar(25), @date, 121)`

Comment: @kez ok write it like.. `var incomplete_product_result = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProductCollection>("FindIncomplete_Products  @type = {0}, @category = {1}, @country = {2}, @subsidary = {3}, convert(nvarchar(25), @date, 121) = {4}", type, category, country, subsidary, date).ToList();`

Comment: @AmneshGoel then I'm getting following error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'.`

Comment: @kez okay.. one thing... why don't u pass this value as a normal string to your SP . .. dont convert it in c# code.. just pass it like other value.. and upon receiving in SP, do the conversion, which will be very easy.. you need to change your SP then a bit..

Comment: **Don't** change dates to strings you will just invite more errors. Bhavik already identified the issue - this part `'%' +  @date + '%'` tries to implicitly cast  `%` to a date. It doesn't make sense - what are trying to do?

Comment: This can be verified by simply running your SP directly - you'll get the same error. This is basic troubleshooting. If things aren't working unit test each piece individually.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid could  you please tell me how can I run my SP directly ?

Comment: Run it in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). Connect to your database and type `EXEC FindIncomplete_Products NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-01-01'` and you will get that error, _without_ anything to do with the web front end

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid ohhh gosh.. thnx man.. I lately understood the date part problem in SP.. I don't understand why he is using `like expression` like that

Comment: @kez still in problem?

Comment: @AmneshGoel still have problem , now all the errors gone away ,but I cannot get any results on frontend view page ,once I put this like `http://localhost:49669/Home/Program_Search?type=null&category=null&subsidary=null&country=null&date=2015/01/01`
.but I can get results when I run following code in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) `EXEC FindIncomplete_Products NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-01-01'`

Comment: @kez okay, that's good.. So can you please tell me what is the type of `incomplete_product_result` .. you are passing this to your view... but to which model this object is mapped?

Comment: @kez can you please show your top 15-20 lines of view page, and tell me what model for `incomplete_product_result`

Comment: @kez to solve your time issue in date, you can use `datediff` function like   `AND (@date IS NULL OR datediff(d,[dbo].[AB_Product].[CreatedDate],@date = 0)` ... this will check the difference between two dates wrt to days.. if both the dates are same (irrespective of time part) then it will return 0 else +/- value..

Comment: @AmneshGoel you correct I'm not mapped correct model properties once SP retrive data , so I created new model, now I can view the results.

Comment: @kez I'll post that as an answer.. you can upvote and accept that.. thanks.. if you have any other problem, then do post

Comment: @AmneshGoel so should I use `datediff` insted of `date` in SP ?? thats ments two changes only in SP `@date datetime` to ====> `@date dateiff` and `AND (@date IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Product].[CreatedDate] = @date)` to ====> `AND (@date IS NULL OR datediff(d,[dbo].[AB_Product].[CreatedDate],@date = 0)` is it ? am I correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89773/discussion-between-amnesh-goel-and-kez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and type

```
EXEC FindIncomplete_Products NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-01-01'
```

and press F5 and you will get that error, without anything to do with the web front end

This issue is this expression:

```
'%' +  @date + '%'
```

You are concatenating a string to a date so it tries to implicitly cast the string to a date, and it certainly cant convert a `%` to a date.

To fix it, change this line

```
AND (@date IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Product].[CreatedDate] LIKE '%' +  @date + '%')
```

To this

```
AND (@date IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Product].[CreatedDate] = @date)
```

in your stored proc

The first line doesn't actually make logical sense. You can't `LIKE` against a date.

This assumes that there are no further issues in the web code.

How did you create the stored proc if you don't know how to use SSMS?

(This is actually all based on @Bhavek's comment - he noticed it first!)

Comment: you're correct now I know SP is working once I run this query `EXEC FindIncomplete_Products NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-01-01'` in my db table I stored date and times not just date then I cannot search only using date

Comment: For example within CreateDate in database table stored like below 2015-08-27 13:28:50.333 , How do I search by only using the date not data and time ,

since this query with `=` parameter for `date` parameter how to filter with the date

Comment: Thanks lot , still have problem , now all the errors gone away ,but I cannot get any results on frontend view page ,once I put this like `http://localhost:49669/Home/Program_Search?type=null&category=null&subsidary=nu‌​ll&country=null&date=2015/01/01` .but I can get results when I run following code in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) `EXEC FindIncomplete_Products NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-01-01'`

Comment: Now that your proc is working I defer to Amnesh to sort out your front end. I suggest you close this question and start a new one, referring to this one

Comment: though I'm not sure if NULL will interpreted the way you think. It's probably passing a string of `'NULL'` in rather than an actual NULL. Work out some valid search parameters and pass those in. You probably need to leave those parameters blank to represent NULL. If you learn to use SQL Profiler you could also troubleshoot this further

Comment: and of course if my answer helped at all please mark as correct so when other people search and find this answer it is of help to them

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes it helped lot

Answer (score 1):

To fix your "data not coming in view" issue, check the model for `incomplete_product_result` which is currently not bind to any model object.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid what is the err, pls?

Comment: See my answer for more info

Comment: @AmneshGoel in your SP, is it should be `@sdate nvarchar(250)` instead of `@sdate datetime` am I correct ?

Comment: **No** never define a date as a string. You'll just cause yourself problems

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Got it.. I lately identified that issue.